# Xcode adhoc provisioning

Tags: ios, xcode, adhoc

I just distributed my first ad hoc provisioning app to my iPad via iTunes and all seemed to have worked fine, except the fact that my app does not show an icon on the iPad, only a silver button.

When I start the app, the screen goes black for around 2 seconds, then the "desktop" is shown again.

I am not sure how I should go on now. There isn't any such thing as a "log file" on the iPad, is there? The reason why it doesn't really start might have a hundred reasons, I guess.

On the simulator it worked fine.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does it work when you connect your iPad directly and run the app from Xcode? Have you used the correct profile? Does the profile contain the iPad's UDID? If you connect your iPad to a mac, you can see the console with the logs from within Xcode.

Comment: A quick question in return, please: Do I have to enter the UDIDs anywhere else, or only at apples website/provisiong portal?

Comment: Maybe this is the reason? -> I updated XCode a few days ago, and when I attach my iPad to my MAC now, XCode is saying (Organizer->Devices) "The version of iOS on "MyiPad" is too old for use with this version of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below (OS installed on "MyiPad" 4.2.1 (8C148). XCode Supported iOS Versions: 6.0 (10A403), 5.1, 5.0, 4.3. I am not sure how to go on from here, but I guess that is the main problem. Before the Xcode update, Xcode did not tell me about this, and it worked fine.

Comment: Xcode 4.5 doesn't support iOS < 4.3. Do you have an iPad 1?

Comment: Yes, I have iPad 1. But before the Xcode update it worked fine, and I need to support the latest iPhone as well. Do I have install 2 Xcodes? Or can I update my iPad to a new iOS?

Comment: As I said, Xcode 4.5 doesn't support building armv6 binaries - so that's older hardware, and it doesn't support building for versions < 4.3. So yes, if you want to support older hardware and OS versions, then you will either need to install two versions of Xcode and use a shared codebase; taking care to correctly write code that will only run methods that are available on the OS, or ditch support for older versions.

Comment: XCode 4.5 doesn't support any arm6 devices, and won't support < 4.3.  If you want your code to run on 4.3 and 6.0 devices, you can set your target to 6.0 and your deployment target to 4.3.
You do need to update your iPad, at least to 4.3 ( and why not 5.1).
with Xcode 4.5, the earliest hardware you can support is iPhone 3GS ( running iOS 4.3+) and iPad 1.0 ( running iOS4.3+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the answers you need in the edits, but to answer the original question.

You only need to add UDIDs in the portal, nowhere else.

You can get crash reports from an AdHoc device.  Sync the device and then look in ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

Alternatively, if it is your device, connect the device and use the Devices panel in the Organizer.

The plain white icon means you don't have an icon set for the deployment device.  I've never had this after setting an Icon.  Check the target summary for any icon errors, they're normally shown next to the icon space.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the great help!